Circle with defined radius (TikZ)
I have a problem with my code: why circle centered in (Center) of radius \def\radius is not outputed? Thank you so much.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=8]
\def\y{3}
\coordinate (A) at (0,0);
\coordinate (B) at (1,0);
\coordinate (C) at ($sqrt(\y)*(0,0.5)+(0.5,0)$);
\path[save path = \Triangle] (A) -- (B) --(C) -- cycle;
\draw[use path=\Triangle];
\coordinate (Center) at ($sqrt(\y)*(0,1/6)+(0.5,0)$);
\def\radius{sqrt(\y)/6}
\draw (Center) circle (\radius cm); % raggio = 0.29
% ($sqrt(\y)/6$ cm);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}


See also \pgfmathsetmacro

Although I am not sure why the actual calculation fails with the explicit centimeter (maybe worth a new question with a really minimal one-line example?), I can add a couple points here:

As said by Jasper, 1 cm is the default x and y vector, so there is no need to add it.
Do not use \def as if it were to calculate anything. Remember, TeX expansion is strictly textual. In this case, it sort of works, but for calculating things with pgf much better to use the \pgfmath... set of macros, as said by John Kormylo.
circle () is obsolete since ages, use circle [radius=...] instead.

This works (once you add the calc library, that you do not have in your example but it's needed):
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[] %  I removed the big scale
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\y}{3}
        \coordinate (A) at (0,0);
        \coordinate (B) at (1,0);
        \coordinate (C) at ($sqrt(\y)*(0,0.5)+(0.5,0)$);
        \path[save path = \Triangle] (A) -- (B) --(C) -- cycle;
        \draw[use path=\Triangle];
        \coordinate (Center) at ($sqrt(\y)*(0,1/6)+(0.5,0)$);
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\radius}{sqrt(\y)/6}
        \draw (Center) circle [radius={\radius cm}]; % raggio = 0.29
        % \draw [red] (Center) circle [radius={\y/6 cm}]; % not sure why but it fails
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}



Why are you specifying cm, considering that it is the base measurement? Do you intend to specify alternate units of measurement later?
anyways, the circle is being drawn very small for some reason when you specify it to be in centimeters:
\documentclass[tikz, border=0.2cm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\newcommand{\Vy}{3}
\coordinate (A) at (0,0);
\coordinate (B) at (1,0);
\coordinate (C) at ($sqrt(\Vy)*(0,0.5)+(0.5,0)$);
\path[save path = \Triangle] (A) -- (B) --(C) -- cycle;
\draw[use path=\Triangle];
\coordinate (Center) at ($sqrt(\Vy)*(0,1/6)+(0.5,0)$);
\newcommand{\radius}{(sqrt(\Vy))/6}
\draw (Center) circle ({\radius cm});
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


With the modification of removing the cm specification, it works:
\documentclass[tikz, border=0.2cm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\newcommand{\Vy}{3}
\coordinate (A) at (0,0);
\coordinate (B) at (1,0);
\coordinate (C) at ($sqrt(\Vy)*(0,0.5)+(0.5,0)$);
\path[save path = \Triangle] (A) -- (B) --(C) -- cycle;
\draw[use path=\Triangle];
\coordinate (Center) at ($sqrt(\Vy)*(0,1/6)+(0.5,0)$);
\newcommand{\radius}{(sqrt(\Vy))/6}
\draw (Center) circle ({\radius});
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


However, I do not purport to know why the cm specification is shrinking the circle.

Thx, if I have \draw (E) arc (49.11: 130.89: 0.60218539682 cm); and if instead of 0.60218539682 I wanted to use \newcommand{\S}{sqrt(1/\b+(sqrt(\a)/2-2/sqrt(\c))^2)} why \draw (E) arc (49.11: 130.89: \S cm); does not function? Thx again

My initial impression would be to put the math in brackets, like this: \draw (E) arc (49.11: 130.89: {\S});,  though I have not actually run it. Using brackets in coordinate specifications throws tikz off, so you need to enclose it in {...}

It does not function, thx anyway

No problem! If someone is able to give a better explanation, feel free to send them the tick btw.
